# ggplot: hide sensible data/microdata

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using `ggplot`, I would like to hide, when the number of cases is less than 4.

For example, when generating a plot using the `esoph` data, I would like to replace the bar with 3 ncases (tobgp = 20-29), so instead of a bar and the number 3, it only writes < 4 for tobgp = 20-29.[image]

Code for generating the plot:

```
library(tidyverse)
esoph |>
  filter(agegp == "55-64") |>
  filter(alcgp =="80-119") |>
  ggplot(aes(x=tobgp, y=ncases)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label=ncases), vjust = -0.5) +
  theme_bw()
```

If anyone has a more general solution to the problem it would be great, as I'm often dealing with cases < 4 in my projects, which I cannot share.

Comment: in `label`, use `ifelse(ncases<4, "< 4", ncases)` instead of `ncases`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use conditional labeling with `ifelse`. However, I would also ensure that the actual value of the column is censored by making it 4 if the true value is less than 4, but reducing transparency or changing color. Otherwise, you have not truly censored the value:

```r
library(tidyverse)

esoph |>
  filter(agegp == "55-64") |>
  filter(alcgp =="80-119") |>
  ggplot(aes(x = tobgp, y = ifelse(ncases < 4, 4, ncases))) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = ncases < 4)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(ncases < 4, "<4", ncases)), vjust = -0.5) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#808080', '#80808080'), guide = 'none')
```

[image]